# Dynamic change of the image in the button

Tags: c++, winapi

I needed to add a picture to the button, I found a method using .bmp format, but it was impossible to remove the background, so I started looking for another way, found a way to load png format, everything works fine with it. But now I need to change the picture when the mouse cursor hovers over the button, I tried to display it via mLoadImg-displayImage, but then the picture appears in the picture, and then it does not disappear at all (for obvious reasons). Please help me make it so that when you hover the image is replaced by another one, or even a different method of adding a picch to the button, thank you

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include "Header.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Msimg32.lib")
#include <gdiplus.h>
#define ID_BUTTON   1
HWND btn;
using namespace Gdiplus;
static HCURSOR hcHand, hcArrow;
const WCHAR* texture = L"close.png";
HBITMAP mLoadImg(const WCHAR* szFilename)
{
    HBITMAP result = NULL;
 
 
 
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(szFilename, false);
    bitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &result);
    delete bitmap;
    return result;
}
 
 
//void CStaticImg::displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HWND mHwnd)
void displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HWND mHwnd)
{
    RECT myRect;
    BITMAP bm;
    HDC screenDC, memDC;
    HBITMAP oldBmp;
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;
 
 
 
    GetObject(mBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
 
 
 
    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xff;
 
 
 
    bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
 
 
 
    screenDC = GetDC(mHwnd);
    GetClientRect(mHwnd, &myRect);
 
 
 
    if (mBmp == NULL)
        FillRect(screenDC, &myRect, WHITE_BRUSH);
 
 
 
    else
    {
        memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
        oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, mBmp);
        AlphaBlend(screenDC, 0, 0, myRect.right, myRect.bottom, memDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, bf);
        SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
        ReleaseDC(mHwnd, screenDC);
 
    }
}
 
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    HBITMAP closeBtn = mLoadImg(texture);
    switch (Msg)
    {
        
        case WM_PAINT: 
        {
        
            if (hWnd == btn)
            {
 
                /*PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                HDC hdc_x = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
                HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"play.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //Load the bitmap
                SelectObject(hdc_x, hBitmap); //Put the bitmap into the hdc_x
                int a = 0, b = 0;
 
 
                if (!hBitmap)
                {
                    MessageBox(0, L"da", L"da", 0);
                    FillRect(ps.hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 151, 151)))));
                }
                BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 200,161, hdc_x, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //Draw it.
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);*/
                
                displayImage(closeBtn, hWnd);
                
                ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL);
 
            }
 
            break;
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
                tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
                tme.dwHoverTime = 1;
                tme.hwndTrack = hWnd;
 
                TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
                
                break;
            }
            case BN_CLICKED:
            {
                printf("da");
                break;
            }
            case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
            {
                SetCursor(hcHand);
                printf("da");
                Sleep(200);
                //InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
 
        default:
            return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            HDC hdc_x = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
            HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"back.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //Load the bitmap
 
            if (!hBitmap)
            {
                FillRect(ps.hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 151, 151)))));
            }
            SelectObject(hdc_x, hBitmap); //Put the bitmap into the hdc_x
 
            //BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, 400, hdc_x, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //Draw it.
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 999, 700, hdc_x, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //Draw it.
 
            HFONT hFont = CreateFont(48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Roboto Th"); //Create the font. (I'm using Roboto Thin.)
            DeleteDC(hdc_x); //Delete the HDC containing the bitmap.
            SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
 
            SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255)); //White text.
            SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT); //Transparent background.
 
            TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, L"We love nice pictures.", strlen("We love nice pictures.")); //Print it!
            
            if (AdminMode::GetAdminMode(1))
            {
                FILE* conin = stdin;
                FILE* conout = stdout;
                FILE* conerr = stderr;
                AllocConsole();
                AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());
                freopen_s(&conin, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
                freopen_s(&conout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
                freopen_s(&conerr, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
                SetConsoleTitle(L"AdminConsole");
            }
            
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
 
            
            break;
        }
 
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            //HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"play.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //Load the bitmap
 
            /*btn = CreateWindow(L"button", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP,
                50, 50, 500 , 200, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            SendMessage(btn, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, LPARAM(hBitmap));*/
            btn = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("START EDITING!"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 975, 10, 14, 14,
                hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);
 
            SetWindowSubclass(btn, ButtonProc, 0, 0);
            hcHand = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND); // удалять не надо, это разделяемые курсоры
            hcArrow = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
            break;
        }
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
        {
            
            LRESULT currentArea = DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
            if (HTCLIENT == currentArea)
                return HTCAPTION;
            return currentArea;
            
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
        
    }
}
int WINAPI  WinMain(HINSTANCE hInsatnce, HINSTANCE hPreviInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    static Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    static ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    // so we can load all the image formats that windows supports natively - (I'm using a transparent PNG on the main dialog)
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
 
 
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.hInstance = hInsatnce;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WinMainClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    hwnd =  CreateWindow(
        wc.lpszClassName,
        L"App",
        WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        //WS_SYSMENU,
        450, 150, 999, 700,
        NULL, NULL, hInsatnce, NULL);
    /*RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
    HRGN rgn = CreateEllipticRgn(20, 30, 150, 110);
    SetWindowRgn(hwnd, rgn, TRUE);*/
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return msg.wParam;
 
}



HBITMAP mLoadImg(const WCHAR* szFilename)
{
    HBITMAP result = NULL;
 
 
 
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(szFilename, false);
    bitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &result);
    delete bitmap;
    return result;
}
 
 
//void CStaticImg::displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HWND mHwnd)
void displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HWND mHwnd)
{
    RECT myRect;
    BITMAP bm;
    HDC screenDC, memDC;
    HBITMAP oldBmp;
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;
 
 
 
    GetObject(mBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
 
 
 
    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xff;
 
 
 
    bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
 
 
 
    screenDC = GetDC(mHwnd);
    GetClientRect(mHwnd, &myRect);
 
 
 
    if (mBmp == NULL)
        FillRect(screenDC, &myRect, WHITE_BRUSH);
 
 
 
    else
    {
        memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
        oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, mBmp);
        AlphaBlend(screenDC, 0, 0, myRect.right, myRect.bottom, memDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, bf);
        SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
        ReleaseDC(mHwnd, screenDC);
 
    }
}
```

Comment: [BM_SETIMAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-setimage).

Comment: Bitmap* pBitmap;
   HBITMAP hBitmap;
   pBitmap = Bitmap::FromFile(L"close.png");
   pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color::White, &hBitmap);
   LRESULT lr = SendMessage(btn, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, 
   (LPARAM)hBitmap);

not working

Comment: This wasn't posted as a solution. It was meant to make you reconsider your entire approach. A [button control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/buttons) is fully capable of displaying an image already. You just need to use the `BS_BITMAP` or `BS_ICON` window styles. No reason to render onto a window, surely not a solution to render onto a window you do not control.

Comment: Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460538/how-can-i-unload-a-picture-from-an-element) mean you don't use BM_SETIMAGE ?

Comment: I tried to use BM_SETIMAGE , but bitmap have white background, i dont need it, so now i trying with PNG

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I display a image when mouse hovering and invalidate button's rectangle when mouse leave.
The following code works for me.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    HBITMAP closeBtn = mLoadImg(texture);
    switch (Msg)
    {

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        if (hWnd == btn)
        {
            /*PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            HDC hdc_x = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
            HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"play.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //Load the bitmap
            SelectObject(hdc_x, hBitmap); //Put the bitmap into the hdc_x
            int a = 0, b = 0;

            if (!hBitmap)
            {
                MessageBox(0, L"da", L"da", 0);
                FillRect(ps.hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 151, 151)))));
            }
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 200,161, hdc_x, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //Draw it.
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);*/

            displayImage(closeBtn, hWnd);
            ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL);
        }

        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
        tme.dwHoverTime = 1;
        tme.hwndTrack = hWnd;

        TrackMouseEvent(&tme);

        break;
    }
    case BN_CLICKED:
    {
        printf("da");
        break;
    }
    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    {
        SetCursor(hcHand);
        printf("da");
        //Sleep(200);
        displayImage(NULL, hWnd);
        displayImage(mLoadImg(L"hover.png"), hWnd);
        break;
    }
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, 1);
        break;
    }
    }

    default:
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: here the image does not disappear, they just overlap each other, it seems that only I do not work InvalidateRect, but still thank you for your effort)

Comment: @Y0MMY Do you mean adding `displayImage(NULL, hWnd);` before ` displayImage(mLoadImg(L"hover.png"), hWnd);`?

Comment: i need to change image when i hover to button, but if just displayImage(mLoadImg(L"hover.png"), hWnd); and one more displayImage(mLoadImg(L"hover2.png"), hWnd); then its will be image on image, i need only 1 image